# Use vsphere_vmfs_datastore to create one DS per volume

Tags: terraform

Following this v0.11 [example from the official documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/vsphere/r/vmfs_datastore.html#auto-detection-of-disks-via-vsphere_vmfs_disks), I had to make minor changes to it to make it work with v0.12 (provider.vsphere is v1.11.0).

```
resource "vsphere_vmfs_datastore" "datastore" {
  name           = "test"
  host_system_id = "${data.vsphere_host.esxi_host.id}"
  disks = data.vsphere_vmfs_disks.available.disks
}
```

This, however, creates a single datastore comprised of all discovered volume. What I want is one new datastore per each discovered volumes.

I tried to use `count = 2` in above resource; with 2 volumes that attempts to create 2 datastores (the good), but each each still comprises the both volumes (the bad).

`vsphere_vmfs_datastore` should count the number of volumes returned by `vsphere_vmfs_disks` (so that I don't have to set it), loop through the list and create one datastore on each, which makes me think this resource section should be inside of a loop and each datastore would assign a unique `name` and use `data.vsphere_vmfs_disks.available.disks.[N]` but I don't know how to do that in `Terraform 0.12` (there are relatively few examples and still some bugs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would the following work for you? It still uses the count method but passes in the count index to select a disk inside of the `data.vsphere_vmfs_disks.available.disks` data source.

```
resource "vsphere_vmfs_datastore" "datastore" {
  count = 2
  name           = "test${count.index}"
  host_system_id = data.vsphere_host.esxi_host.id
  disks = [
    data.vsphere_vmfs_disks.available.disks[count.index]
  ]
}
```

Unfortunately I don't have an ESXi host I can test against, but the logic should still apply.

Comment: It indeed does! Thank you! If I recall correctly I tried to use the curly brackets for `count.index` in disks list (the way it's used in `name`). This answer is acceptable (although I'm still curious if `count` could be dynamic, but that detail can become my next homework)

Comment: Glad it works! I have to admit I’m still figuring out the for loops in 0.12